# Low percent vs moderate percent credit card limit effect on credit score

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I was wondering if spending more (50-89%) or less (1-25%) of credit limit increases or decreases credit score depending on the amount spent on the credit card. I have recently turned 18 and became employed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spending a reasonable amount (<30% of the limit), and paying it fully off every month, will certainly help your credit score.

However, there are several large components that constitute credit scores, and the other factors are probably much more significant: payment history (so make sure to pay your bills, rent, etc. on time, every time); average age of accounts (so don't close your oldest accounts), bankrupties (don't have any, of course), and some more.

If you keep those in mind, your credit score will increase over time, and your credit limit will increase too. Remember that a high credit score means that your payment history shows that you are a good debtor, and pay as agreed. There is no shortcut to a good history- it takes time and consistency.

Comment: It's important also to note that being a responsible debtor who always pays will earn a "great" credit score, but the high end of "excellent" is reserved for those who are highly profitable -- they never skip out on their debts, but they miss payments, take cash advances, trade-in for a fraction of book value, and various other ways of racking up extra fees that go directly to the bank's bottom line.  The behaviors associated with perfect credit scores benefit only the lenders, not the owner of the score.

Comment: I think that is completely wrong. Credit scores are not made by the companies that earn fees from you.

Comment: No, but credit scores are sold to the companies that earn fees from you, and their design is influenced by the desires of their customers.  The consumer is not the customer.

Comment: You should try that opinion on sceptics.se, because I don't care to spend more time proving the opposite in comments. I think it's a baseless rant and wrong, and I know lots of examples that prove so.